# X11 EvDev Touchscreen Driver : Disable Long-Press Right-click on desktop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, evdev

I'm setting up a kiosk system that automatically loads a webpage in full screen on boot-up. Standard stuff.

The problem is a hooked up an Acer touch screen which works fine with the evdev driver... but it works a little too well. If the user presses and holds down on the screen, a right-click is generated and the context menu appears. This causes a few problems for the interface and I need to disable this feature, but I haven't found a way to do that yet.

X11 configuration files are not something with which I have much experience. Does anyone have any experience getting rid of this feature? Is it possible to map the touchscreen to a generic mouse driver?

The system is:
- Ubuntu Mate 15.04
- Raspberry Pi 2
- Window Manager: Matchbox
- Browser: Chromium

So far, I've made the following changes to the 10-evdev.conf file in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d

```
Section "InputClass"
 Identifier "evdev touchscreen catchall"
 MatchIsTouchscreen "on"
 MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
 Driver "evdev"
 **Option "ButtonMapping" "1 0 0 0 0"
 Option "Emulate3Buttons" "False"
 Option "EmulateWheel" "False"
 Option "EmulateThirdButton" "False"
 Option "EmulateThirdButtonTimeout" "100000"
 Option "EmulateThirdButtonMoveThreshold" "0"**
EndSection
```

None of it has had any effect on the right-click event being generated or the context menu appearing. However, if I put:

```
Option "Ignore" "on"
```

The touchscreen doesn't work at all, so I believe that is the proper section to change.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I've been struggling with the same thing and thought I'd post my solution in case there are others like me out there:
Ubuntu 22.04, Wayland disabled in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf by un-hashing the 'WaylandEnable=false line (i needed to calibrate my touchscreen, doing this was the only way I could, but that's a different topic).
I did as originally suggested, editing the usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf file to include the settings wanted, eg

Option "EmulateThirdButton" "1"

Option "EmulateThirdButtonTimeout" "750"

Option "EmulateThirdButtonMoveThreshold" "30"

I rebooted and nothing happened, but then stumbled onto the accessibilty options - toggle the 'mouse keys' option to "on" and voila! long press on the touchscreen brings up the right click menu.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend not changing the distribution-provided xorg.conf snippet but rather stacking your own on top, see here http://who-t.blogspot.com.au/2014/03/stacking-xorgconfd-snippets.html

Emulate3Buttons should be the right option, do make sure it shows up in the xorg.log though. Any option that is parsed by the driver is printed there, if it never shows up then it's not detected.